# How to find the maximal and minimal strictly positive difference between two subset sums of a vector?

Tags: r, optimization

I searched for this but I could not find anything that seemed to match; if anyone could please help or point me in the right direction, it would be great.

Suppose you have a numerical vector `h = c(-1,-2,3,5,6,9)` (I'm using R).

You make 2 different selections of 3 elements of this vector. You take the sum of each selection and then the difference between the two sums.
E.g. one selection could be `c(-1,3,5)` --> the sum is 7; the other `c(-2,3,9)` --> the sum is 10; the difference is 10-7 = 3.

You want to know:

- the largest possible (positive) difference
- the smallest possible *positive* difference

For a small vector like this one you can just go brute force, you get all possible differences between the two sums, and you just look up the desired values.

```
h = c(-1,-2,3,5,6,9)
N <- length(h)
n <- 3

vs <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),2*N))

vs["np1"] <- rowSums(vs[,1:N])
vs["np2"] <- rowSums(vs[,(N+1):(2*N)])

vs <- vs[(vs$np1 == n) & (vs$np2 == n),]

vs["hSum1"] <- apply(vs,1,function(x) sum(h*x[1:N]))
vs["hSum2"] <- apply(vs,1,function(x) sum(h*x[(N+1):(2*N)]))

vs["hdiff"] <- vs$hSum2-vs$hSum1

max(vs$hdiff)
#[1] 20
min(vs[vs$hdiff > 0,"hdiff"])
#[1] 1
```

Clearly though this is not possible for larger vectors.

I figured out that the largest difference can be found by simply sorting `h` (ascending) and taking the difference between its last 3 and first 3 elements:

```
sum(sort(h)[(N-n+1):(N)]-sort(h)[1:n])
#[1] 20
```

However, I can't figure out a solution for the smallest *positive* difference.
I tried linear programming, but I can't find a trick to impose the strict inequality on the difference, which (I think) would be required to avoid getting 0 as a solution.
In this sense, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608529/select-the-smallest-strict-positive-value-from-a-list-of-variables-in-a-linear-p) would seem conceptually close, but I can't get my head around it because I don't see where the method comes from, and when I applied it as such without trying to understand it, it did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** - possible LP solution to find the smallest positive difference

By iteration.
Let `Dmin` be the sought difference. I start by finding an upper bound for `Dmin`, as the smallest pairwise difference between unique elements of `h`:

```
h <- c(2.1,1,-0.5,0,1.7,2.3)
N <- length(h)
n <- 3

min.hdiff <- min(diff(sort(unique(h))))

UB <- min.hdiff
UB
#[1] 0.2
```

The lower bound can be set to 0:

```
LB <- 0
```

In this case, it is clear that `UB` is not `Dmin`; it can be checked by brute force that `Dmin` is 0.1.

To reproduce that by LP, I first define a function that looks for the *max* (not *min*) *positive* difference *comprised between LB and UB*:

```
obj <- c(h,-h)

constr.n1 <- c(rep(1,N),rep(0,N))
constr.n2 <- c(rep(0,N),rep(1,N))
dir.n <- "=="
rhs.n <- n

constr.D <- c(h,-h)
dir.D1 <- ">="
rhs.D1 <- LB
dir.D2 <- "<="
rhs.D2 <- UB

mat <- rbind(constr.n1,constr.n2,constr.D,constr.D)
dir <- c(dir.n,dir.n,dir.D1,dir.D2)
rhs <- c(rhs.n,rhs.n,rhs.D1,rhs.D2)
N.rhs <- length(rhs)

require(Rsymphony)

DS.feas <- function(LB,UB) {
  rhs[c(N.rhs-1,N.rhs)] <- c(LB,UB)
  LP.sol <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj,mat,dir,rhs,types="B",max=T)
  if ((LP.sol$status == 0) & (LP.sol$objval > 0)) {return(list(1,LP.sol$solution,LP.sol$objval))} else {return(list(0,NULL,LP.sol$objval))}
}
```

Then I check that the initial [LB,UB] is feasible:

```
LB.feas <- DS.feas(LB,UB)

LB.feas
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.2
```

As the current `[LB,UB]` is feasible, in the next iteration I test the midpoint between `LB` and `UB` (`MB`) as the new putative `UB`:

```
MB = (LB+UB)/2
MB
#[1] 0.1
MB.feas = DS.feas(LB,MB)
MB.feas
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.1
```

Feasible. So I set `UB` to `MB` and test the new, lower (but still positive) midpoint:

```
UB = MB
MB = (LB+UB)/2
MB
[1] 0.05
MB.feas = DS.feas(LB,MB)
#MB.feas
#[[1]]
#[1] 0
#
#[[2]]
#NULL
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0
```

Not feasible. So `Dmin` must be between the current `MB` and `UB`. I set `LB` to `MB` and run the next iteration.

And so on until convergence is achieved.

I tested this on various vectors.
It seems to work; only, it becomes very slow already for `N = 20`.

If anyone can suggest how to do this better...

Comment: How many elements can h have? As for the linear programming, you can use a variable to count the amount of same numbers from both sets. Restrict that to be < 3

Comment: Thanks juvian. h can have any number of elements. I am not sure I understand your suggestion. Yes, I can count the number of equal elements in the two sets, but how does that help? I can get a difference of 0 even when the two subsets have all different elements. This can be shown by: `vs["absvecdiff"] <- apply(vs,1,function(x) sum(abs(x[1:N]-x[(N+1):(2*N)])) )`, `vs[(vs$hdiff == 0) & (vs$absvecdiff == 6),]`.

Comment: I assume you want to use this with many numbers, because up to 1000 elements it should be fast enough to calculate all possible 3 sums, sort them and check lowest difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know r, but I'm sure you can formulate the same problem as this python solution:

```
from pulp import *

vals = [-1,-2,3,5,6,9]
r = range(0, len(vals))

#group1[i] = 1 if we use vals[i] in first group
group1 = LpVariable.dicts('group1', r, cat='Binary')
group2 = LpVariable.dicts('group2', r, cat='Binary')

#repeats[i] = 1 if we allow to use vals[i] in both groups
repeats =  LpVariable.dicts('repeats', r, cat='Binary')

prob = LpProblem('test', LpMinimize)

sum1 = lpSum([group1[i] * vals[i] for i in r])
sum2 = lpSum([group2[i] * vals[i] for i in r])

#objective
prob += sum1 - sum2

#make group1 be highest sum to prevent negative solutions
prob += sum1 >= sum2

#make each group have 3 items
prob += lpSum([group1[i] for i in r]) == 3
prob += lpSum([group2[i] for i in r]) == 3


#dont allow choosing same number for both groups if we are not allowing repeat
for i in r:
    prob += group1[i] + group2[i] <= repeats[i] + 1

#only allow up to 2 repeats (thus preventing same solution repeating 3)
prob += lpSum([repeats[i] for i in r]) <= 2

prob.solve()

print([vals[x] for x in r if group1[x].value()], [vals[x] for x in r if group2[x].value()])
```

**Edit**: Just reread your question and seems you don't want to allow solution 0. In that case it is even easier, can remove everything related to repeats and just change first restriction to:

```
#avoid solution 0
prob += sum1 - sum2 >= 1
```

Comment: Thanks juvian, that's great. I will get Python installed and try it out. A colleague of mine kept telling me to learn Python; now I have a very good reason to do it. So I seem to understand you're using an LP solver like I did. One very interesting point you make is the one about the difference of the two sums being >= 1. I suppose that only works for integer-valued vectors. I did not mention explicitly that my vector is usually real-valued, so my example may be misleading. Still, nothing stops me from multiplying the vector by a large constant that makes it integer. Then I can run a single LP

Comment: @user6376297 yeah I assumed they were integers, but if not they can be made integers as you said. Or maybe change the 1 for 0.0001 or similar depending on amount of decimals you use. Don't remember if that works but you can try ^^

Comment: In fact I am trying now and I see that real vectors have so many decimals that it's not possible to convert them to integers. So I will have to round them to a specific number of decimals before I start this. In fact this suggests that the initial vector should be rational rather than real; or people should decide a priori the number of significant digits. If the vector is made of euclidean distances, of course it can have irrational values. Anyway, thanks again, I think we are on the right path now.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest difference is actually the partition problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

The largest difference is all negatives in one subset and the positives in the other

Comment: Thanks karpada. The Wikipedia page does indeed refer to an 'optimization version' of the partition problem where the difference between the two subset sums is minimized (rather than 0), but then does not elaborate on that. I will see if I can find more information elsewhere. As for the largest difference, I think choosing by negative or positive does not apply to my case, where there are not even 3 negative elements.

Comment: @user6376297 - The problem in question is not a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) problem - with a partition, _every element is included in exactly one subset_, while in the question's example, `3` is in both subsets and `6` is not included.

Comment: If items are allowed to be used in both subsets, then one can use the same subsets yielding a difference of 0. 

E.g. one selection could be c(-1,3,5) --> the sum is 7; the other c(-1,3,5) --> the sum is 7; the difference is 7-7 = 0.